# What's servers are Hyper-V host in a network?

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

In a company network, how I know what's machines(servers) are Hyper-V hosts using powershell ?

Comment: hyper-v Hosts (not guests)?
Ask VMM.

Comment: Virtual Machine Manager - The Server, which manages hyper-v guests and Hosts. Take a look into hyper-V concepts, if you do not know them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to ask network admin.

In case that's not feasible, there are a few ways. First off, you can [query serviceConnectionPoint](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/find-all-hyper-v-hosts-and-windows-virtual-machines-in-your-ad-environment/) from AD. That lists all computers that have Hyper-V role enabled. In case of link rot, here's a snippet

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$hostDN = Get-ADObject -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "serviceConnectionPoint" -and Name -eq "Microsoft Hyper-V"'
$hostDN | ForEach-Object { $_.DistinguishedName.Split(",")[1].replace("CN","") }
```

You could also check registry for key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters`. It is updated by integration components, and doesn't exist on physical systems.

Comment: Looks good, however only shows 'hyper-v' dedicated servers, does not show servers with hyper-v roles installed.